# using ch=getchar to get integer input values from the user in c++ does not gives the expected result

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Hi i Have the following code

```
# include <iostream>
# include <limits>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,x=0,f;
    cout<<"Enter the number of voters:";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    char ch;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        ch=getchar();
        switch(ch)
            {
        case '1':
            a++;
            break;
        case '2':
            b++;
            break;
        case '3':
            c++;
            break;
        case '4':
            d++;
            break;
        case '5':
            e++;
            break;
        default:
            x++;

            }
    }

    cout<<"Votes for 1 is :"<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Votes for 2 is :"<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"Votes for 3 is :"<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"Votes for 4 is :"<<d<<endl;
    cout<<"Votes for 5 is :"<<e<<endl;
    cout<<"Votes for others is :"<<x<<endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I am trying to get integer input values from the user and  using switch statement to count the different values  based on the user inputs .

when i execute the program, if i have given the n value as 5 , am able to input only two integer values and the output is displayed as follows

```
Actual Output : Enter the number of voters :5
1
2
Votes for 1 is :1
Votes for 2 is :1
Votes for 3 is :0
Votes for 4 is :0
Votes for 5 is :0
Votes for others is :3

But my expected output is :
Output : Enter the number of voters :5
1
2
3
4
5
Votes for 1 is :1
Votes for 2 is :1
Votes for 3 is :1
Votes for 4 is :1
Votes for 5 is :1
Votes for others is :0
```

Comment: you have `x++` but have not declared it, did you mean `f` ? BTW f should be initialized too.

Comment: you may want to consider using an array instead and then use index e.g. `arr[ch-'0']++` then you don't need the switch statement, you just need to check the character to be in the range

Answer (score 0):

The character `'1'` is not the number `1`. The character `'1'` is (almost certainly) the number `49`. Use `'1'`, with single quotes, for the character.

Also, `getchar` isn't going to skip newline characters. The 5 characters it's reading are newline, 1, newline, 2, and newline. I recommend sticking to `cin` to read the votes.

Comment: I have given single quotes but my output is  not the expected one. My Output is after including single quotes is  : Enter the number of voters :5.
1
2
Votes for 1 is :1
Votes for 2 is :1
Votes for 3 is :0
Votes for 4 is :0
Votes for 5 is :0
Votes for others is :3 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @user3027039: Answer extended.

Comment: I used cin instead of getchar , i got the expected output , Thanks :) user2357112.

Answer (score 0):

Using getch() does not work fine.
use the statement cin>>

```
    char ch;
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
       cin>>ch;
      switch(ch)
           {
```